# How can one overcome the disadvantage of studying in less prestigious international school for admission in top 10 Math PhD programs?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, undergraduate

I am a international applicant. I study in fairly less prestigious undergraduate school. I am aware that this will have a affect on my Grad School Applications. Since I am freshman I was wondering of how I can minimize the disadvantage. I do think of four possible ways:

1. Taking toughest courses possible:
   My school is kind of a unique model. It has very less permanent faculties. It usually borrows Math professors from other institutions in my country which sort of have a international reputation. They usually offer grad level courses known as electives. I do have the option of taking as many of them. I won't run out of these courses. However the undergrad transcript will not show the name of professor under which the class was taken. I am kind of skeptical how admission committee will judge these courses just by looking at name of undergraduate institution.
2. Amazing letters of recommendation :
   Since good and internationally known faculty take courses at my school I do hope to get recommendations from them. This should 
   help but I am not sure how much.?
3. Budapest semester in mathematics and IMC :
   I am sure BSM will help however will doing really good in IMC make my application better ?
4. Good honors thesis: 
   I do have the option of completing my honors thesis abroad at a different institution. Usually honors thesis don't contain publishable material however that's a matter of hard work. It won't be published before the application deadline but will a letter from advisor highlighting the work and results of my thesis do any good ?

Even if I check each one of the above box's how worthy and comparable my application will be to those from the very best undergrad schools ?

Comment: Looks like a good roadmap. But note that it is easy to make big plans and difficult to carry out all of them: BSM for instance is challenging and it would be hard to get good grades in it...

Comment: In previous questions and answers, people have mentioned (math) graduate programs asking applicants to list the textbooks they used in their classes rather than who the professor was.